# Why isn't the compiler noticing that a boolean has been declared true?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, boolean

In this method:

```
 private void implementVisibility(EditText A, EditText B, ImageButton C, boolean visible) {
   if (visible) {
     A.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     C.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
   else if (!visible) {    // warning here
   }
 }
```

At the `else if (!visible)` line I get the warnings:

> Condition !visible is always true
> Value visible is always false

But looking at the calling method:

```
if (count2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
  implementVisibility(count2, action2, remove2,true);
}
```

`visible` *is* `true`, therefore it isn't *always* false. Why doesn't the compiler notice this?

Comment: Just use **else** instead

Comment: Just read your code. First you are asking "is this true"; and if that is not the case you are asking "is this not true". Hint: you don't need that second question; that is the idea of boolean - it is either true or false. And hint: A, B, C, are really poor names for variables. The law prohibiting to use more than one character per variable name was abolished late 1979 I think ;-)

Comment: there is just two possibilities in boolean, So if and else statement will be enough

Comment: Do you mean, at the line:implementVisibility(count2, action2, remove2,true); the compiler must notice that the last param is always true?

Comment: @berserk it says that the Boolean is always false, yet in one method I pass that boolean as true

Comment: @AbAppletic It doesn't say that the boolean is always false. I says !visible will always be false in else statement, because the control will go to else statement only when if statement fails. Now if statement will fail only when visible is false. So, whenever else statement is executed, visible will be always false, hence, !visible will be always true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time program control gets to `else if(!visible){`, `visible` can **only** be `false`.

Your compiler is hinting that you should clarify your code to `else {` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Boolean variable only have 2 values true or false, so that you should edit your code as belows:

```
private void implementVisibility(EditText A, EditText B, ImageButton C, boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            A.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            C.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            // do something
        }

    }
```